# Powershell : Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership for every computer in my AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm quite stuck atm.
I'm trying to write a script that will get me every computer in my AD and the groups they are in a .csv. Something that would look like this:

[image]

I tried with that kind of line:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties Name,OperatingSystem,IPv4Address,MemberOf | Select-Object Name,MemberOf,OperatingSystem
```

But it doesn't work. And when i'm trying with `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`, i can't put `get-adcomputer -Filter *` with it.

Comment: _"...it doesn't work"_ What are you getting as compared to what you expect?

Comment: You do not need Filter is you are getting all computers.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to decide if you want to take top-down or bottom-up approach. I'm thinking top-down is easier to grasp and (probably) more performant.

Either way this is a little more complex than a one liner. You'll need to do recursion; neither LDAP now Powershell's internal implementation return a parent's ancestry or a child's descendants.

There IS Get-AdGroupMember -Recursive but that will list only the (leaf) members of a group (anything that's not a container) and its descendant groups; it will NOT list any containers. So you can use that to get all the PCs in a set of groups. You can't however use it to get a group hierarchy.

You can use Get-AdGroupMember for a top down approach, grab all the objectClass=computer objects in there, then for each objectClass=group in the result set, feed that list into Get-AdGroupMember again (and maintain a list of the group names) until there are no longer any groups in the resultset.

You can also use Get-AdPrincipalGroupMembership for a bottom up approach and then trace membership paths upwards while listing any "inode" group names you find along the way. Here too the list of results (that will always be groups, obviously) will need to be fed into Get-AdPrincipalGroupMembership again until the result set is empty.

Do be aware that there may well be distinct traces for each computer object to an ancestor group, either intentional or not, so for each PC object you need to provide for multiple results.